# Send \r or \n via phone serial monitor

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth adapter connected to uno, and using a serial monitor on phone.

In the arduino code im debugging there is this line waiting for new line signal in the serial stream:

```
char c = SerialBT.read();

if (c == '\r' || c == '\n'){
```

no matter what i try sending to via my phone i cant get this to evaluate as true...

if i send \n , i believe it is sending it as 2 chars \ and n , not as a single char.

is this a problem with the phone app or what ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a problem with the android terminal program i was using, by switching to another that specifically has support and options for \n \r things it works now.

Comment: If you had used third party app terminal, and in `EditText` field you wrote `Hello World\n` then yes it will send it as '\' and 'n' because it reads them  as chars.